# Polymer: Binding links to core-animated-pages

Tags: polymer

I'm trying to use polymer animated pages but it's
returns an error on the console:

```
 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'selected' of null
```

here is the code

```
<core-animated-pages id="pp" selected="0">
    <section id="signin">
            aa
            <a href="/#" onclick="hi()">cc</a>
     </section>
     <section id="signup">
        bb
     </section>
<core-animated-pages>
<script>
    function hi(){
         var pp = document.getElementById('pp');
         pp.selected='1';
    }
</script>
</template>
<script>


    Polymer({});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me. Note: `selected` should be set to an integer index, not a string.

```html
<script src="http://www.polymer-project.org/platform.js"></script>

<link rel="import" href="http://www.polymer-project.org/components/core-animated-pages/core-animated-pages.html">

<core-animated-pages id="pp" selected="0">
    <section id="signin">
            aa
            <a href="/#" onclick="hi()">cc</a>
     </section>
     <section id="signup">
        bb
     </section>
<core-animated-pages>

  <script>
    function hi(){
         var pp = document.getElementById('pp');
         pp.selected= 1;
         return false;
    }
</script>
```